# Linux - Execute shell scripts simultaneously on the background and know when its done

Tags: linux, rsync

I'm using `rsync` to transfer files from a server to another server (both owned by me), my only problem is that these files are over 50GB and I got a ton of them to transfer (Over 200 of them).
Now I could just open multiple tabs and run `rsync` or add the "&" at the end of the script to execute it in the background.

So my question is, how can I execute this command in the background and when its done transferring, I want a message to be shown on the terminal window that executed the script.

```
(rsync -av -progress [FOLDER_NAME] [DISTINATION]:[PATH] &) && echo 'Finished'
```

I know thats completely wrong but I need to use & to run it in the background and && to run echo after rsync finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next to the `screen`-based solution, you could use `xargs` tool, too.

```
echo '/srcpath1 host1 /dstpath1
    /srcpath2 host2 /dstpath2
    /srcpath3 host3 /dstpath3'| \
xargs -P 5 --max-lines 1 bash -e 'rsync -av -progress $1 $2:$3'
```

`xargs` reads its input for stdin, and executes a command for every single words or lines. This time, lines.

What it makes very good: it can do with its child processes parallel! In this configuration, xargs does this by using always 5 parallel child processes. This number can be 1 or even infinite.

xargs will exit, if all of its childs are ready, and handles every ctrl/c, child processing, etc very well and problem tolerant.

Instead of the `echo`, the input of `xargs` can come from a file, or even from a previous command in the pipe, too. Or from a `for` or `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

You could use gnu screen for that, screen could [monitor](http://aperiodic.net/screen/monitoring) output for silence and for activity. Additional benefit - you could close terminal and reattach to screen later - even better if you run could screen on server - then you could shutdown or reboot your machine and processes in screen still be executing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to answer your specific question, your invocation:

```
(rsync ... &) && echo 'Finished'
```

creates a subshell - the `( ... )` bit - in which `rsync` is run in the background, which means the subshell will exit as soon as it has started `rsync`, not after `rsync` finishes. The `&& echo ...` part then notices that the subshell has exited successfully and does its thing, which is not what you want, because `rsync` is most likely still running.

To accomplish what you want, you need to do this:

```
(rsync ... && echo 'Finished') &
```

That will put the subshell itself in the background, and the subshell will run `rsync` and then `echo`. If you need to wait for that subshell to finish at some point later in your script, simply insert a `wait` at the appropriate point.

You could also structure it this way:

```
rsync ... &
# other stuff to do while rsync runs
wait
echo 'Finished'
```

Which is "better" is really just a matter of preference. There's one minor difference in that the `&&` will run `echo` only if `rsync` doesn't report an error exit code - but replacing `&&` with `;` would make the two patterns more equivalent. The second method makes the `echo` synchronous with other output from your script, so it doesn't show up in the middle of other output, so it might be slightly preferable from that respect, but capturing the exit condition of `rsync` would be more complicated if it was necessary...